# Python - Bubble sorting data from an external text file

Tags: python, algorithm, file, text, bubble-sort

I have developed a simple bubblesort algorithm, which works when the variable myList = say, [1,4,2,3,5], but I need to load the text from an external text file. This is what I have.

```
#New Bubble sort
f = open('Users/Luke/Dropbox/Programming/numbers.txt', 'r')
my_list = f.read()
print(my_list)
length = len(my_list)

for i in range(length):
    for j in range(length-1):
        if my_list[j] > my_list[j+1]:
            my_list[j], my_list[j+1] = my_list[j+1], my_list[j]
            print(my_list)

f.close()
```

This returns me with:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/Luke/Dropbox/Programming/numbers.txt'
```

The directory does exist, and I've tried different variations (back/front slashes, including 'C:/') etc.

Comment: beware that you are not parsing your 'numbers.txt' file. you'd better parse them into a list with only `int`s : is `','` bigger than `'1'`?

Comment: Looks like Os X path, right?

Answer (score 1):

You missed first '/'
`/Users/Luke/Dropbox/Programming/numbers.txt`

Comment: I fixed this, and got the same error. I'll add that I tried opening  a text file in Linux and it worked. Is there a special protocol for opening text files under windows?

Answer (score 0):

You need back slashes instead of forward slashes like this:

`file = open('C:\\Users\\Luke\\Dropbox\\Programming\\numbers.txt' ,'r')`

And since the backslash is an escape character, you need to add two of them (the first one escapes the second one)

Comment: Windows can also read forward slashes, and it makes it easier on the eye.... test it yourself.

Comment: @InbarRose, I didn't realize that. Makes sense for portability. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something like:

```
'C:\\Users\\Luke\\Dropbox\\Programming\\numbers.txt'
```

Or

```
r'C:\Users\Luke\Dropbox\Programming\numbers.txt'
```

Remember `'\'` is an escape character in Python.

Answer (score 0):

To get the absolute definitive path to a file:

- go to the file, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right-click</kbd> and then select 'Copy as Path'
  from the menu.
- Or open the files properties and get its folder name, and then you
  can combine its name together for a full path.
- Or you can create a shortcut, and then look at the properties of the
  shortcut to see the target location.
- Or you can drag the file into an open Console and see what path shows
  up.

In other words, this should not be a problem to determine...

To deal with this in your program in case it is open to input, check `os.path.exists(path)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use os.path
Specificaly: os.path.join
This function handles path delimiters for you, so it will be always correct independent from os.

Like: 


from os import path
my_path = path.join('Users', 'Luke', 'Dropbox', 'Programming', 'numbers.txt')

For further info, see:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html